# How do i load an array/collection to a DatagridViewcombobox cell?

Tags: c#, winforms

i have the following `datatable`

```
DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
dt3.Columns.Add( new DataColumn("COL5") );
dt3.Rows.Add( new object[] { "dodge" } );
dt3.Rows.Add( new object[] { "cruz" } );
dt3.Rows.Add( new object[] { "billy" } );
dt3.Rows.Add( new object[] { "hasmper" } );
```

i have used the following method to load the table data to `DataGridViewComboboxColumn`

```
 DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvCombCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
 dgvCombCol.DataSource = dt3;
 dgvCombCol.DisplayMember = "COL5";
 dataGridView3.Columns.Add(dgvCombCol);

    dataGridView3.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView3.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView3.Rows.Add();
```

but it does not display any rows or `comboboxes` with values, when click the drop down arrow of a `combobox` it displays nothing. Is there away to this?

If further information required, please let me know!

Comment: Can you create a minimum working example that reproduces this error?  I created a `Form`, added a `DataGridView`, dropped your code in the `Form` constructor, then ran it and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure **enable editing is checked**, if not, by clicking on the drop down will not make the control go to edit mode and no dropdown.

in the designer,  select your Datagridview control then click the little arrow on the side and check enable editing!

HTH